# Identifying Arduino-compatible board signatures in code

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I am developing libraries for compatibility across a number of Arduino/compatible boards. I know that Arduino boards can be identified by the test "#if defined (**AVR_ATmega328P**)" and compatibles as well: #if defined(**TM4C123GH6PM**).   There are a few lists of these IDs on the web but are all outdated. I have searched various cores and library code and do not see where these defines are actually defined.

Nick Gammon's [Sketch to detect Atmega chip types](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) identifies the chip type. What I'm looking for the board type to define pin configurations, etc.

Where and in what format are board signatures stored? Is there c++ code that can find the board signature? Does anyone know of a site where these signatures are stored and updated by the Arduino community?

Answer (score 1):

In the `boards.txt` file each board has a board type definition, such as:

```
uno.build.board=AVR_UNO
```

When you compile your sketch that is adapted into a "board" define by prepending `-DARDUINO_` to it and adding it to the compilation command line - so that one becomes the same as `#define ARDUINO_AVR_UNO`.  You can, of course, test for it with:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_AVR_UNO
....
#endif
```

The location of the `boards.txt` file varies with different versions of the IDE, but every installed core will have one.  Look around in your Arduino program folder in the `hardware` subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks, Majenko. That one has been bugging me for months.